# Make spaced caps bold in classic thesis environment

Tags: bold, classicthesis

In a classic thesis environment I want to make spaced caps bold. Can somebody tell me how to do this since `\textbf` is not working properly?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{changepage}


\begin{document}

{\color{Maroon}\noindent\footnotesize\spacedallcaps{Personal Information}}\vspace{1pc} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\bfseries`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage{color}


\begin{document}

{\color{Maroon}\noindent\footnotesize\bfseries\spacedallcaps{Personal Information}}\vspace{1pc}

\end{document}
```

[image]